# How do I position a div under a fixed position div

Tags: html, css, position

I have a position:fixed div at the top of my page, so that when a user scrolls down the menu always stays at the top.

How do I position another div element underneath the fixed div.

I'm using CSS and HTML.

[image: layout]

I'm using a smooth scrolling jQuery and need each section header to appear just under the menu bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this — http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/pJyMGb:

**HMTL:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
    <div class="menu-item">About</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Demo</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Contact</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item menu-item_sub">Contact</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
}

    .menu-item_sub {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 60px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do everything in absolute position domain.

```
.1(class){
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top20px;
}
```

Like above classify each object with a class and set their position.